# How to say this?

Tags: meaning, word-request

Look I want to ask about a verb that hardly I can describe, so maybe an expert could edit this post or I'll do it after some feedback.

What is the correct verb that when I'm describing a topic (say `A`) for somebody and in the progress of my description I also give him information about another topic (say `B`) and he
[I don't know what to say] gets B wrongly as A and I want to say him don't [???] get the notions switched to each other!

**Hint**: In my language we say don't mix these with each other.

OMG, I completely understand if you don't get what I mean.

Comment: "Don't mix them up" sounds good enough for me. You can also say things like "Don't mix B up with A," or "Don't mistaken B for A," too.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Thank you, so it's really close to what we use. I just searched what you said in babylon and it's very correct. I mean the case that I wanted.

Comment: Aw! feedback is a single word and the plural is the same!

Comment: @MaulikV: Do you mean it's like Data that is the same in single and plural?

Comment: @mok you got it!

Comment: @DamkerngT. Isn't mistaken P.P. of mistake? I mean shan't we use sth like "Don't mistake B for A"?

Comment: @mok you got it again! The closest I think is *mistaken/took*

Comment: @mok You're correct, sorry for my half-typo-half-mistake. It should be "Don't mistake B for A" as you said.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the verb *mistaken or mistook*.

> [mistaken (v)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/MISTAKE) - Identify incorrectly

This example shall make it clear:

> When I said Paul that I liked Jane and not Julie, he *mistook* my statement and thought I liked Julie and not Jane.

Comment: Thanks,I didn't get the point from the comments :) May I use mistaken in the present time? And do you agree about "mix up" with  Damkerng T.?

Comment: @mok Sure, Damkerng's comment is fine. And yes, you can use it in the present tense. *Don't mistake her for her twin sister.*